# Lista separada por "-"

Tags: python, lista

O tema é o seguinte:

Tenho uma lista[1,5,3,6,22,45,63,30,344,22,12,25,10]

E queria imprimir os elementos dessa lista numa só linha e separados por “-”.

Já tentei dessa forma

```
    lista=[1,5,3,6,22,45,63,30,344,22,12,25,10]
>>> newlista = lista.split('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você quer desmembra os itens e guardar em uma variável de que forma? Outra lista idêntica? Não faz sentido fazer isto porque o resultado será idêntico.

Uma das formas de fazer o que deseja é:

```
print(*lista, sep = '-')
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Console/ListSep.py).

Assim a lista entra como itens seguido em vez do objeto como um todo, e tem o argumento `sep` para definir o separador.

Também é possível fazer com um `for`.

Comment: Era mesmo isso!!

Comment: Com um for?!?! como assim?

Comment: >>> lista=[1,5,3,6,22,45,63,30,344,22,12,25,10]
>>> print(*lista, sep = '-')
1-5-3-6-22-45-63-30-344-22-12-25-10
>>>

Answer (score 5):

Apenas para ficar com outra alternativa, pode utilizar a função [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) de `string` para atingir o seu objetivo. Esta permite-lhe juntar vários elementos formando uma nova `string` com um separador definido por `si`:

```
>>> lista_em_texto = '-'.join(map(str, lista))
>>> print(lista_em_texto)
1-5-3-6-22-45-63-30-344-22-12-25-10
```

Primeiro começa com o separador chamando a função `join`:

```
'-'.join(
```

Depois vem os elementos que vão ficar com o separador à volta, que seria a `lista`. Neste caso como a lista tem valores númericos, estes tiveram de ser convertidos em texto com a função `map`:

```
map(str, lista)
```

Este `map` mapeia cada um dos números para texto utilizando `str` em cada um deles.

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/mNd5XT)

Naturalmente também consegue fazer tudo numa só instrução se quiser:

```
print('-'.join(map(str, lista)))
```

Utilizando [*list comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) também consegue a conversão de forma ligeiramente diferente:

```
>>> lista_em_texto = '-'.join([str(num) for num in lista])
>>> print(lista_em_texto)
1-5-3-6-22-45-63-30-344-22-12-25-10
```

Neste ultimo caso é mais evidente que faz `str(num)` para cada numero que está na lista, gerando assim uma nova lista só com os números em `string`, sendo essa a utilizada no `join`.